# How do I count each word in a file using Java

Tags: java

Im trying to write a program with three instance methods, but I cant seem to get it right. My method wordCount returns the number of lines in the file. Not the number of words as its supposed to.

Im just lost in the method mostFrequentWords..

Hope someone can help me out

```
package opgaver;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TextAnalysis14 {
    Scanner file;
    int CountWords = 0;
    boolean Contains = true;
    String[] words;
    String[] MFwords;

    public TextAnalysis14(String sourceFileName, int maxNoOfWords) {
        String wordline;
        words = new String[maxNoOfWords];
        String[] line;

        try {
            file = new Scanner(new File(sourceFileName));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            file = new Scanner("");
        }

        while (file.hasNext()) {
            wordline = file.next();
            line = wordline.split("[^a-zA -Z]+");
            for (int i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
                if (!line[i].equals(" ")) {
                    words[CountWords] = line[i];
                    CountWords++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (words[CountWords] == (null)) {
            for (int i = CountWords; i < maxNoOfWords; i++) {
                words[i] = ("empty");
            }
        }
    }

    public int wordCount() {
        return CountWords;
    }

    public boolean contains(String word) {
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            if (words[i].contains(word)) {
                return Contains;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String[] mostFrequentWords() {
        Arrays.sort(words);
        return MFwords;
    }
}
```

Comment: You sort `words` and then return a totally different array that you only ever declare and never use again? HUH? Explain more about what this method is meant to do.

Comment: What do you call a word?

Comment: that method am I still working on!

But the method is meant to return the most frequent words in the file. Im thinking about using a for each loop or something?

Comment: a word for me is a non-empty string consisting of only of letters (a,. . . ,z,A,. . . ,Z) surrounded
by blanks, punctuation, hyphenation, line start or line end.

Answer (score 0):

by calling `wordline = file.next();` you are not reading lines.

In `TextAnalysis14` change your condition to `file.hasNextLine()` and read lines with `file.nextLine()`

```
while (file.hasNextLine()) {
    wordline = file.nextLine();
    ....
}
```

Comment: And change if condition as file.hasNextLine()

Answer (score 0):

Because of my noob status I cannot make a comment but it looks like you have a space in your regex between A and -Z.

Answer (score 0):

try with this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "this    is    a space String"; // read all lines in a file
    String[] splited = str.split(" ");
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0;i < splited.length; i++){
        if(splited[i].length() > 0){
            list.add(splited[i]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list.size());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like that using Java 8:

```
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("c:/", "file.txt"));
in wordCount = lines.mapToInt(s -> s.split(' ').length()).sum();
```

This function just cound a words count in file.

Comment: what about if two more spaces in between words??

Comment: In that case length of array in between "space" and "space" will be 0.